# How to loop through all subfolders in a directory, and remove files with a specific filename

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a script in Powershell to remove some files automatically with a certain file name.

My idea is to get all the folders in the directory, then loop through the subdirectory, and remove all items with the file name, but it doesn't seem to be working as expected.

Here is my script

```
$folders = Get-ChildItem -path "C:\Website-Backup" -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PsIsContainer} |Group-Object {$_.FullName.Split('_')[0] }
$subfolders = Get-ChildItem -path $folders -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PsIsContainer} | Group-Object {$_.FullName.Split('_')[0] }

ForEach($subfolder in $subfolders)
{
    Remove-Item * -Include *100x*
}
```

Any idea why the script doesn't seem to be doing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can simplify your code if I understand correctly to:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Website-Backup" -Recurse  -include "*100x*" -file | remove-item
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Group-Object` command is likely what's confusing things here - `Remove-Item` is expecting a path - you're not referencing the subfolder variable in your loop as well, so this is the same as just running the `Remove-Item` command as many times as there are items in the array.

You can try this instead;

`Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Website-Backup" -Recurse | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.name -like 'MyFile.txt' } | Remove-Item`

This will pipe the returned child items into `Where-Object`, filter it to the specified file name, then pass that to `Remove-Item` as a file path.

You can also skip the `Where-Object`, but you lose a bit of control this way;

`Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\WebSiteBackup\*MyFile.txt' -Recurse | Remove-Item`